# Recommendations/tips/improvements for a training program with my current gear

Tags: training, exercise-equipment, dumbbells, muscle-groups, tips

I am 18 years old, 66kg (146lbs) and 180cm (5'11").

Gear: treadmill, power tower (pull/chin-ups and dips), two dumbbells with weights of 30kg (max. of 20kg per dumbbell), a resistance cable and a WonderCore II which I could use for a bench for dumbbell presses and sit-ups.

I am currently thinking about a training scheme, preferably every day except Friday. I have some experience but am completely new to pull-ups and dumbells. I would mostly want to train my chest, back, biceps, triceps and abs, since I train legs enough during cycling and running. I would prefer to not do too much cardio since I would like to gain a lot of muscle and my stamina is already sufficient.

Scheme:

Monday: Chest (dumbbell press, diamond pushup, chest dips) + triceps (tricep dips, diamond pushup, two-arm tricep extension).

Tuesday: Biceps + shoulders (bicep curls, pull-ups).

Wednesday: Back (chin-ups,?).

Thursday: Cardio (20 min running or HIIT with sprinting).

Saturday: Abs (sit-ups especially).

So my question is, what could I do on Sunday or how should I shuffle some of the muscle groups per day since this is hard to decide on for me. Also, do you know of any other good exercises (for my back and abs or anything else) with the equipment I've got? I will find warming ups on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not train your entire body at once? Specially the traps,lats and chest always work together in movements like dips, pull ups or push ups, it makes no sense to separate them.

But anyway I'm going to suggest some exercises.

Legs/Back/Glutes

**Reverse hyperextension**, just place a dumbbell between the legs to increase intensity, use a bench or table, the ball is optional

Serratus/Trapezius/Chest/Back/Tricep

**Pullovers** Probably the best exercise for the lats and chest in my opinion, the weighted stretch is so beautiful it makes you feel like you can actually control each muscle individually. Breathing during this movement feels incredible, almost as if the guts and lungs were getting a massage, plus this exercise can aid vacuum progression. I strongly suggest doing this movement everyday, it will get you addicted in a good way.

As another bonus it carries over to dips, push ups,swimming,pull ups and rope climbing.

This exercise is the deadlift that works your upper body.

Obliques/Serratus/Trapezius/Abdominis

**Writer leg raise** Hang off a bar and by lifting the legs in front as in a leg raise try to draw letters, names or just the alphabet on air using your legs.

To increase intensity start actually drawing things for bigger ranges of motion or put a dumbbell between your legs

Comment: Thank you! These exercises are definitely great. I heard from some friends that you should never train too many muscle groups together and should always keep it to 2/3, but I guess that’s not necessarily the best option then, since you train most of them together anyways.